# How to I create a dynamic disco floor shader?

Tags: shaders, emission

(I'm quite new to complex shading in Blender, so I might be missing something obvious)

I'm trying to make a dynamic shader that replicates a disco floor - flashing squares that light up in a checkerboard pattern, and I've got this far:

[image: Node Setup]

I'm using an offset Voronoi texture for random colour, a checkerboard to define the groups of squares, a #frame value to control the speed of the flashing, and some maths to define whether to show a glossy or emission for each square. However, it only creates a flashing Vorinoi texture, and completely ignores the checkerboard.

How do I correct this? Thanks for any help

(This shader could be used for a shape with curved faces, so generating individual squares wont do, like [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/89wa38/suggestions_on_how_to_approach_a_disco_floor_tile/) Reddit post suggests)

BTW, please ignore the uncalibrated scale option

Comment: Perhaps a helpful YT tutorial [How to make a Disco Floor in Blender](https://youtu.be/gNu25XhaBns)

Comment: it would be helpful if you show us how it should look like...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the division of the red value by 255 behind the checker texture.

The red value will be between 0 and 1. If you divide it by 255 it will be about 0.004 at the white squares and 0 at the black ones. Thus the checker texture will be eliminated by the modulo that follows later.

You could even remove the *Separate RGB* node and connect the *Fac* output of the *Checker Texture* directly with the *Add* node.